# Firestore - Store nested custom objects

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Firestore WV9, and i want to store 2 DTOs :

**DeckDTO**

```
export class DeckDTO {
  descriptor: DeckDescriptorDTO
  format: DeckFormat = DeckFormat.Classic
  size: number = 0

  constructor(id: string) {
    this.descriptor = new DeckDescriptorDTO(id)
  }
}

const deckConverter: FirestoreDataConverter<DeckDTO> = {
  toFirestore(deck: DeckDTO): DocumentData {
    return {
      descriptor: deck.descriptor,
      format: deck.format,
      size: deck.size
    };
  },
  fromFirestore(snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DeckDTO>): DeckDTO {
    const data = snapshot.data()
    const deck = new DeckDTO(data.descriptor.id)
    deck.descriptor = data.descriptor
    deck.format = data.format
    deck.size = data.size
    return deck
  }
}

export { deckConverter };
```

**DeckDescriptorDTO**

```
export class DeckDescriptorDTO {
  id: string
  title: string

  constructor(id: string, title: string = "") {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
  }
}

const deckDescriptorConverter: FirestoreDataConverter<DeckDescriptorDTO> = {
  toFirestore: (dto) => {
    return {
      id: dto.id,
      title: dto.title,
    };
  },
  fromFirestore: (snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DeckDescriptorDTO>, options): DeckDescriptorDTO => {
    const data = snapshot.data(options);
    return new DeckDescriptorDTO(
      data!.id,
      data!.title
    );
  }
};
export { deckDescriptorConverter };
```

As you can see, `deck` contains a `deckDescriptor`

**Storing my DTOs**

I can store the `deckDescriptorDTO` perfectly

```
      const docRef = doc(this.db, 'descriptors', dto.id).withConverter(deckDescriptorConverter)
      await updateDoc(docRef, dto);
```

But it dont work with the `DeckDTO`, saying *Unsupported field value: a custom DeckDescriptorDTO object (found in field descriptor)*

```
      const docRef = doc(this.db, 'decks', deck.descriptor.id).withConverter(deckConverter);
      await setDoc(docRef, deck);
```

Comment: For now i did exctract the second object from the first, stored it separatly and get it with a common id.